# Is there any way to intercept a grandchild process creation?

Tags: c, winapi, process, posix

I have two applications written in C, `foo` and `bar`. The `foo` program will create a new external process through `system()`.

Is there a way I could detect if that subprocess invokes the `bar` process?

E.g., `foo` invokes `make`, and during the build process, `make` invokes `bar`. How could I detect this so that I could make `foo` and `bar` "talk" to each other?

I could do it naïvely by using an environment variable, but I wanna know if there is any other way.

Also, I could have two instances of `foo` running on the same time, and each of them should only talk to their grandchild `bar` processes.

(Answers for both Windows and POSIX will be appreciated.)

Comment: Does it matter that there is one (or more) processes between `foo` and `bar`? With e.g. named sockets you could make the connection, regardless of how the processes were started.

Comment: Use a [Mutex Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266.aspx) to detect and prevent, that the process `bar` is instantiated more than once.

Comment: Usually there will be only one process between `foo` and `bar`, @unwind. But ideally it should detect on any depth. I wouldn't like to use the filesystem for this (though named sockets or named pipes would be a good idea).

Comment: If I've understood your problem statement correctly, an environment variable is a reasonably good solution.  One other possible approach in Windows would be a job object, which would allow `foo` to detect that `bar` has been launched; `bar` could listen on a named pipe whose name is based on the process ID.  That's probably more complicated than it is worth, though.

Comment: I didn't know about job objects, seems like a great way to go. Do you know if there is anything like that on POSIX?